# Are there any good articles or tips about the Nginx resolver module?

Tags: proxy, nginx, dns, resolver

I can't seem to find any good tutorials on what can be done with `ngx_resolver`. For example I am trying to find the best way to dynamically update the `proxy_pass` directive in a vhosts file.